# How do I replicate block of code to appear below only reserved position for image

Tags: html, css, css-float

Heres the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/NtMNE/

I want to repeat the code block below, only on the second block have the image on the right side. Thought it would be simple but have hot road blocks....

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="block1"
    <p><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture" id="intro_pic" ></p>
    <h2 id="intro">
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!
    </h2>
</div>

    <div id="block2"
    <p><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture" id="intro_pic2" ></p>
    <h2 id="intro2">
        The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the `h2` title to have the same width as the image and fit like a caption?

Comment: Let me take a look at it.... give me 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```
<div class="ex1">
    <img src="http://s15.postimg.org/vl0o8vobf/cheese_owner.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture">
    <h2>The best selection of cheese I've ever seen! Cannot wait for our next order!</h2>
</div>
```

```css
.ex1 {
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.ex1 img {
    float: right;
}
.ex1 h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #2B9BD4;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/LxDMs/

I simplified the HTML a bit.  The image floats to the right as you want and the text will flow around the image if it is long enough.

I adjusted some of the padding and margin to get a more compact look.

I also set up Example 2 that shows how to position the text as a caption beneath the image.

The CSS for Example 2 would look like:

```css
.ex2 {
    border: 1px dotted lightblue;
    width: 200px;
}
.ex2 img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.ex2 h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #2B9BD4;
}
```

Set a width to the wrapper element and scale the image to fit.  The header will then fill up the width of the parent and sit below the image.

Comment: Hi Mark, its example one that I want to use, basically as you have it in fiddle only replicated again on the line below.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, the whole block can be replicated as often as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="block2"
<p><img src="img/cheese1.jpg" alt="Cheese Picture" id="intro_pic" ></p>
<h2 id="intro2">

</h2>
```